# trigger jLabel mouse event from password field "enter" keypressed (custom button)

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, mouseevent

I have created a simple jForm login application. This form contains two text fields for user name and password and another custom made button from a jLabel. In this button I have written all the event listeners such as mouseEntered, mouseExited, mousePressed, mouseReleased and mouseClicked. I need to trigger this mouseClicked event when the user hits enter after entering the password.

How can I do this?

P.S. I have used the Robot class and it seems to be not a proper solution.

Comment: *"a simple jForm"* No such class in the J2SE. Please don't talk like your IDE.

Comment: BTW - See [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377) For this, I'd create an `ActionListener` that can be attached to a `JButton` **or a** `JTextField`. Note the password control should be a **`JPasswordField`** ..

Answer (score 2):

You're going a lot of trouble to avoid the appearance of a `JButton`. Instead, use a `JButton` and invoke `setBorderPainted(false)` to get the appearance of a `JLabel`. Then you can invoke [`setDefaultButton()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JRootPane.html#setDefaultButton-javax.swing.JButton-), and the button "will be activated when a UI-defined activation event (typically the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key) occurs in the root pane regardless of whether or not the button has keyboard focus."

[image]

```
JFrame f = new JFrame("ButtonTest");
f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
JButton b = new JButton(new AbstractAction("Login") {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
});
b.setBorderPainted(false);
f.getRootPane().setDefaultButton(b);
f.add(b);
f.pack();
f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
f.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer @trashgod . How can I get rid of the weird gradient background of the jButton

Comment: @AdeeshaSavindadeSilva: that's a Mac [*screenshot*](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/99734/how-do-i-create-a-screenshot-to-illustrate-a-post) feature, not a button feature.

Comment: Not in your image. But my java button has a gradient background. I did remove this using jButton1.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));. But this makes a strange border around the icon image..

Comment: @AdeeshaSavindadeSilva: That sounds like a feature of your chosen L&F.  Please edit your question, or pose a new question, to include a [mcve] that shows your current approach. Does the default button work?